# Tool to see HTML5 Web SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, html, web-sql

Does anyone know of a tool (like PHPMyAdmin or similar) that will allow me to view the HTML5 Web SQL databases within my browser?

Comment: -1. do not use tag 'tools' see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tools/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of SQLite browsers out there for various systems.  I love [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) because it's just a plugin for Firefox.  On my OSX Lion install the sqlite files are located here: `/Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/1e3lwibu.default/`, but you can just do a search on your system for the location using the extension `.sqlite`.

Answer (score 2):

Developers tools (aka F12 tools) provided by Google Chrome browser is your best bet. In fact it helps you see not just web SQL databases but you can also see localStorage, sessionStorage, IndexedDB, cookies etc.

Here is the navigation path:

```
Google Chrome -> Press F12 -> Application tab -> Storage Node in left navigation bar -> Web SQL node -> <Database Name> node
```

[image]

More details on this is available [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage).